# How to replace img with css

Tags: html, css

i want to replace some pictures (buttons) on a website using "Stylish"

```html
<div id="navigation"><center>
  <a href="index.php" title="Home"><img src="image.jpg" title="Home" alt="Home"/></a>
  <a href="?s=top-rls" title="Top Releases"><img src="image2.jpg" title="News" alt="News"/></a>
<div>
```

I want to replace each image separately !
Is there a way without the "class"-tags?

Comment: what is *Stylish*? What are you trying to achieve exactly? I don't clearly understand your problem.

Comment: [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=de) is a browserplugin that replaces css-code

I want to use css to replace the images. but i don't know how

Comment: Replace the images with what exactly? You can target them without `class` using the `[attribute]` selector: `#navigation img[src="image.jpg"]` for first image or `#navigation img[title="News"]` for second image... You can't use CSS to change image source but you can maybe hide the images with `display: none` and then create something else using a pseudo element added to the parent anchor links

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just don't want to add a class, it's possible to style each image based off it's "title" attribute, if you're sure that is not going to be modified later. But it's still better long-term to style it by class.

Although you can't actually replace images with css, but you can make them invisible and add a background to them. This means both will be loaded. If at all possible you could save yourself the trouble and just change them in the html or their source.

Comment: Please only answer questions with actual answers.

Comment: If I could comment I would have done that instead. Still, if all he wants to do is add an image, it's still a valid answer.